# Layer comps to files with auto trim

Tags: photoshop-script

I am using the modified 'Comps to files.jsx' script to export my layer comps (using the label of the layer comp as my file name)
http://www.ps-scripts.com/bb/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=5277

It is a great script and makes my worklfow so much easier.
The only thing missing for me is a trim option, as some of the layer comps have different heights
After I ran the script, I have to manually crop all the jpgs in PS and then save them out again.
In the default 'Layers to Files' script that comes with PS, there's an option to auto trim .png's when exporting the layers.

Any help on the following questions is much appreciated:

1. I've modified the original 'Comps to files' script and I now have the option (if I choose png as my file type) to trim the layer, but when I open the exported file it din't crop it.
   http://adobe.ly/1r3f3nZ
2. Is there an option to auto trim jpgs?

Thank you